# Change project architecture

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-databinding

i want to improve my project architecture. my app working with Sq lite with server posts once in a while. 
my question is,
is it better to use Data binding library or should i continue work with view id's?
is it make it easier to bind data and work with multiple object on the same view?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose your app mainly works with database and rarely with API calls. Data binding mainly comes to rescue you when we need to bind data from the API calls. So better approach would be skipping use of data binding

Comment: Accurate. i cant trust mobile network in this case so i have to work mainly offline. i thought about data binding because i need to connect multiple objects to my views (the objects connected with id parameter).